# how to get modified keycode of keypress - java

Tags: java, swing, awt

I am using java KeyEvent to get the keycode of a pressed key. How can I easily get the key code of a modified version of this key. For example if the user pressed the "c" key I would want to get the keycode for "Control + c" without the user typing control c. I then want to use the keycode to get the integer character code of the modified key press.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I wouldn't get any event that comprises the "press of control" if the user didn't press that key. You should be able to generate such an event yourself and emit it via `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemEventQueue().postEvent(...)` though.

Comment: There is no keycode for control+c. Keycodes are codes for, as the terms says, a key, not a combo. Modifier keys are represented within the, well, *modifiers*.

Comment: I didn't realise that they did not have key codes. However I still wish to find the character code so I can ultimately get the unicode e.g. control + c has the character code 3 which I will then convert to \u0011

Comment: As @Holger explained already there is no key code for *Control C*.
You probably want the key stroke for *Control C*:
`KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_C, InputEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK)`

Comment: The character code *is* its Unicode code point (for BMP characters). Why do you want to change three to seventeen?